# Help solving $\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{{e^{-{{\left({\frac{t}{2}} \right)}^2}}}{e^{-i\omega t}}dt}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I need help with what seems like a pretty simple integral for a Fourier Transformation. I need to transform $\psi \left( {0,t} \right) = {\exp^{ - {{\left( {\frac{t}{2}} \right)}^2}}}$ into $\psi(0,\omega)$ by solving:

$$
\frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\psi \left( {0,t} \right){e^{ - i\omega t}}dt}
$$

So far I've written (using Euler's formula):

$$\psi \left( {0,\omega } \right) = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\psi \left( {0,t} \right){e^{ - i\omega t}}dt}  = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\left( {\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{e^{ - {{\left( {\frac{t}{2}} \right)}^2}}}\cos \omega tdt - i\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{e^{ - {{\left( {\frac{t}{2}} \right)}^2}}}\sin \omega tdt} } } \right)$$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\left( {{I_1}  - i{I_2}} \right)\\ \end{array}$$

I just don't recall a way to solve this integrals by hand. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) tells me that the result of the first integral is ${I_1} = 2\sqrt \pi  {e^{ - {\omega ^2}}}$ and for the second $I_{2}=0$. But on my notes I have ${I_1} = 2\sqrt \pi  {e^{ - {{\left( {{\omega ^2}/2} \right)}^2}}}$.

Can anybody tell me how one can solve this type of integrals and if the result from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is accurate? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is trivially $I_2=0$ because $e^{-k\cdot t^2}$ is an even function for any $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ whereas $\sin (\omega t)$ is an odd function, thus their product is odd and its integral on $[-\infty,\infty]$ is $0$, as it cancels out.

The first one calculated by Mathematica gives me also $2\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\omega^2}$, so maybe there is a typo in your notes. Notice that those types of integrals are expressible in terms of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), and are by no means elementary. You should use the [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform) operation directly, using its properties, instead of calculating explicitly the integrals, just as when applying Laplace transformations to solve differential equations.

Answer (score 2):

There are some elementary properties of the Fourier transform for $f(x) = e^{-x^2/2}$ that will save you a lot of grunt work. The proofs are left to you, but essentially only require some basic manipulations and the fact that $f$ [decays very rapidly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space#Definition). Let $\hat{ \cdot }$ denote the Fourier transform operator.

(1) $\hat{ [xf(x)]} = i \frac{d}{dx} (\hat{f}) (x)$

(2) $\hat{[ \frac{d}{dx} f(x)] } = i x \hat{f} (x) $

Note also that $f$ arises naturally as a solution to the differential equation $\frac{df}{dx} + xf =0$ so that $\hat{f}$ necessarily satisfies this equation as well by properties (1) and (2). Thus $\hat{f} = C f$ - the normalizing constant is recovered by evaluating the standard Gaussian integral. Now for the Fourier transform of $e^{-x^2 / 4}$ you simply need to make a change of variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you complete the square in the argument of the exponentials, $$ -\frac{1}{4}(t^2 + 4i \omega t) \to -\frac{1}{4}(t^2+4i\omega t -4\omega^2) -\omega^2 = -\frac{1}{4}(t+i2\omega)^2-\omega^2. $$ After a change of variables $u=\frac{t}{2}+i\omega$, the integral becomes $$2e^{-\omega^2}\int_{-\infty -i\omega}^{\infty -i\omega} e^{-u^2}\ du,$$ which, apart from the pesky factors of $-i\omega$ in the bounds, is a standard Gaussian integral equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$. As a physicist, I'm inclined to just sweep these factors under the rug, but we can do better: if we form a contour in the complex plane along the paths $(-\infty,i0)\to\ (\infty,i0)\to(\infty,-i\omega)\to(-\infty,-i\omega)\to(-\infty,i0),$ the integrand kills the contributions moving in the imaginary direction, and the overall integral is zero since $e^x$ has no poles. So, our integral is equal to the one along the real axis, and we can discard the $-i\omega$ terms.